# Как это называется в JS?

Tags: javascript

с JS знаком очень мало, в основном пытался что нибудь делать на JQ. 
Как это реализовать

```
let form= document.forms.namedItem('my_form');
form.my_method({id: "name_id"}) // .my_method({}) как его создать
```

могли бы вы подсказать про что почитать?

Comment: `form.my_method = function(obj) {/*тут ваша реализация*/}`, ето создание функции, а в вашем примере вы ee вызываете передавая туда `{id: "name_id"}`

Comment: $("#myform").validate({
  debug: true
}); В этом примере .validate({}) это метод, или ранее созданная функция?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.prototype` может добавлять функции (методы), которые в дальнейшем будут работать для любых элементов указанного вида:

```js
HTMLFormElement.prototype.my_method = function(obj){
  this.id = obj.id; // this == элемент, который вызвал функцию
};

Array.prototype.bubufy = function(){
  for( var i = 0; i < this.length; i++ ){
    this[i] = 'bubu-' + this[i];
  }
  return this;
}

/*********/

let form = document.forms.namedItem('my_form');
form.my_method({id: "name_id"});

console.log( [1, 2, 3].bubufy().join("; ") );
```

```css
form[id] input {
  border-color: red;
} /* Красный цвет рамок - индикатор, что функция сработала */
```

```html
<form name="my_form">
  <input>
  <input>
</form>
```

Но не стоит лезть туда со своими функциями по поводу и без) Большинство задач решаются через обычную функцию в виде `my_function( form, obj )`

```js
let form = document.forms.namedItem('my_form');
my_method( form, {id: "name_id"} );

function my_method( elem, obj){
  elem.id = obj.id;
};
```

```css
form[id] input {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="my_form">
  <input>
  <input>
</form>
```

Хотя функцию можно добавить и конкретному элементу. Но мне сложно придумать пример из реальной жизни, где это может пригодится)

```js
let form = document.forms.namedItem('my_form');

form.my_method = function(obj){
  this.id = obj.id;
}

form.my_method({id: "name_id"});
```

```css
form[id] input {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="my_form">
  <input>
  <input>
</form>
```

Comment: А вот с jquery validation `.validate({})`, там используется прототип, или это совсем другая реализация,? хотелось бы об этом почитать, а так спасибо за примеры